# Защита от XSS атак

Tags: xss, php, mysql

Всем привет, если на сайте присутствует такая уязвимость:

```
site.com/index.php?page=1<script>alert("XSS")</script>
```

Как можно защититься от нее? Просьба поподробнее.

Допустим:

```
<?
    if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        getInfo($_GET['page']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Парсить <script> и убирать

Answer (score 1):

По минимуму хотя бы так:

```
$page = strip_tags($_GET['page']);
```